# JSON Structure - Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

I finally managed to get data from facebook!

But I have a problem displaying the data, I hope someone can help me :)

[image: Screenshot from the json file]

If I want to get the id for example. Wouldn't it be something like this?

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
              $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/neonlachs/feed?access_token=173359892783474%7Cz-fqFn6DBGIbHfvRT7eQ88v9Uts&callback=?", function(facebookdata) {
                $.each(facebookdata, function(i,face) {
                   console.log(face.json.data[i].id)
                });
              });
           });
```

Comment: Well... does it work? You should read about arrays and objects. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: No. TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Comment: Your code is very close, but you may be accessing the objects/arrays incorrectly. I can help you better if you provide the raw JSON response, or the code to get the JSON reponse.

Comment: Do `console.log(face)` first, have a look at the structure and continue from there. There is not much to say about accessing array elements and object properties, you just have to access the correct ones. You have the data, have a look at it, do it step by step. You should also read about `$.each` so that you know what it is actually doing. The way you use `i` in the callback does not make sense...

Comment: One thing about the inspector you're using: There isn't actually a `json` property in the data. "JSON" is simply a label the inspector gives the anonymous, root object (stored as `facebookdata`). So, `facebookdata.data[0].id` is all you need to get the 1st `id` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you're trying to get is within the data object, not the entire set of data returned within the JSON. You need to specify facebookdata.data as the array to want to iterate over.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/neonlachs/feed?access_token=173359892783474%7Cz-fqFn6DBGIbHfvRT7eQ88v9Uts", function(facebookdata)
    {
        $.each(facebookdata.data, function(i, face)
        {
            console.log(face.id);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Okay so next topic for me is about arrays & objects!